# What object types can be used for fetures in decision trees? Do I need to convert my "object" type to another type?

Tags: python, types, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I imported a table using pandas and I was able to set independent variables (features) and my dependent variable (target). Two of my independent variables are "object type" and my others are int64 and float64. Do I need to convert my "object" type features to "class" or another type? How can I handle these in Sci-kit learn decision trees?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html):

> Able to handle both numerical and categorical data. Other techniques
>   are usually specialised in analysing datasets that have only one type
>   of variable. See algorithms for more information.

So you can run it with object type and int64 and float64. This is one of the benefits of the decision trees, that it can also work with non-numeric data.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. if you click the algorithms section, last line says `scikit-learn implementation does not support categorical variables for now`. So object type will have to be pre-processed for meaningful results

Answer (score 0):

I used `one hot encoding` to convert my categorical data because the `scikit-learn decision tree` packages do not support categorical data.